# PKIX path building failed - unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, ssl, minecraft-forge

JVM info: Oracle Corporation - 1.8.0_51 - 25.51-b03
java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
Found java version 1.8.0_51
Added Lets Encrypt root certificates as additional trust
Target Directory: .
Data kindly mirrored by CreeperHost at https://www.creeperhost.net/
Extracting main jar:
Extracted successfully
Considering minecraft server jar

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraftforge.installer.DownloadUtils.getConnection(DownloadUtils.java:243)
    at net.minecraftforge.installer.DownloadUtils.downloadManifest(DownloadUtils.java:307)
    at net.minecraftforge.installer.json.Util.getVanillaVersion(Util.java:73)
    at net.minecraftforge.installer.actions.ServerInstall.run(ServerInstall.java:86)
    at net.minecraftforge.installer.SimpleInstaller.main(SimpleInstaller.java:128)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 25 more
```

Failed to download version manifest, can not find server jar URL.
There was an error during installation

/* I already tried adding creeperhosts certificates to java's cacert. keep in mind I don't have any experience with this thing.... :DDDDD So I can only follow your instuctions. */

Comment: Hi Hunor, can you please indicate which client certificate is being used, then we can find out which certificate path is required. You can enable [Java SSL debugging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) for this. If it is simply the same as the link you've provided then you can get the root certificate from your browser as well.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Hello, so I basically got the certificate from my browser by going to creeperhosts website and going under the lock icon and exporting the certificate from there. I have 0 knowledge in this topic so I really have trouble understanding what I have to do here.

Comment: Itś probably best to go all the way down and get the root certificate from that site, and put that in the `cacerts` trust store using e.g. `keytool`.

Comment: I used this command line: C:\Windows\system32>keytool -import -alias Something -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\lib\security\cacerts" -file "C:\Users\Huni\Downloads\creeperhost.net.crt"

Comment: I still get the same crash log on the forge installer.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you're installing the root cert. You have got to listen to people, otherwise this debugging session becomes ever so worse.

Answer (score 1):

After spending some time trying to find a solution, i've open the installer's code and found the URL that the installer tries to use to download the files for the minecraft server.

```
    public static final String MANIFEST_URL = "https://launchermeta.mojang.com/mc/game/version_manifest.json";
```

So you must export the root certificate from this link, and import into you JRE truststore. The certificate name is "DigiCert Global Root G2". The command to do so is:

```
 keytool.exe -import -alias digicert -keystore 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\lib\security\cacerts' -file 'C:\Users\[you user here]\Downloads\DigiCert Global Root G2.crt'
```

Usually the password for the truststore is "changeit" (without the quotes).

Now you can run the installer and it should work properly.

Comment: There is no such thing as the ‘JRE trusted certs folder’. Fixed it for you.